# Qt pass additional argument to slot AND keep emitted signal data

Tags: c++, qt, networking, web, qt5

I have searched the web on this issue and I've repeatedly got answers referring to the use of **[QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSignalMapper.html)**. But my problem is pretty clear, **[QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSignalMapper.html)** automatically gets rid of whatever is originally emitted and replaces it with basically ***nothing***, plus the new data that is set via **setMapping()**.

The problem here is simple.

I have a QNetworkAccessManager that parses html and updates a vector containing text data:

```
void DataManager::startHttpRequest(QString url, int index)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    //QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);    
    //connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), signalMapper,SLOT(map()));
    //signalMapper->setMapping(manager, index);    
    //connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(insertUpdate(int)));

    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(finishHttpRequest(QNetworkReply*)));    
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
    qDebug() << index;
}
```

and here is what happens when the request is finished, the normal way:

```
void DataManager::finishHttpRequest(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QString html = QString(reply->readAll()).simplified();
    QString info;
    int start = html.indexOf("<span id=\"SalePrice\" >");
    if(start != -1)
    {
        QString price = html.mid(start + 23, 30);
        int end = price.indexOf("</span>");
        info = price.mid(0, end - 1);
        qWarning() << price.mid(0, end - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        info = "NA";
    }

    // Do more stuff
}
```

Using the normal way of signals and slots, I would not be able to know the **index** of the vector I am updating,

Or,

If I am using **QSignalMapper**, I ***know*** the index, but not the data that comes with it.

How do I get **BOTH** working (index + data)?

(something like `mySlot(QNetworkReply *reply, int *index)`, but we all know that won't work)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I solved it. Haha! Using manager->setObjectName(QString &name) and via manager->objectName(). I'll test it in-depth later tonight and see if this works on a larger scale.

Comment: 1) Don't create a brand new QNAM object for every request. Create only one and reuse it. 2) Just save in a member variable the mapping `QNetworkReply` -> index and then access that mapping in your slot (you get the `QNetworkReply` when you call get()). Potentially, create just a *trampoline slot* which fetches that index and reemits a signal carrying both QNR and index arguments.

Answer (score 1):

While it's probably not the best,

- `sender()->setObjectName(const QString & name)` allows the sender to name itself.
- The sender's name can be accessed from the receiving slot via `sender()->ObjectName()`

As documented on http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop.

Comment: Another way would be to use dynamic properties.